# IOS Custom UIBarbuttonItem change position in detail view

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to customize my navigationbar's UIBarbuttonItem so that I'm using this im my Appdelegate.m

```
// didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 

{
  UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar.png"];

  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:5
                                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



  UIImage *barButtonSave = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2, 0, 2)];


[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButtonSave
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


return YES;
```

}

When I'm done with this I just place a UIBarbuttonItem with Storyboard and I'm done.
The point is I noticed that the "Save" button changes between my views!

It looks like is moving down few pixels in my DetailView:

[image]

Why is That?

Comment: Is it this line: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:5
                                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why. but I solved giving my custom UIbarbuttonItem image the 30px default height.

[see similar issue UIBarButtonItem shifting downwards after a UINavigationController push